# NavigationExperimental Can't render overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to render overlay with NavigationTransitioner ?

```
<NavigationTransitioner
    navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
    configureTransition={this.configureTransition}
```

> renderOverlay={this.renderOverlay}

```
    render={() => (
      <NavigationCard
        navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        cardStyle={styles.container}
        onNavigateBack={this.routeBack}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*renderOverlay* is not supported now, Instead you can use *NavigationHeader* , which you can put in your render function something like this

```
render={() => (
  <View>
    <NavigationCard
      navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      cardStyle={styles.container}
      onNavigateBack={this.routeBack}
    />
    <NavigationHeader {...props}/>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, And one question please, how it possible to not unmount scene on navigation ?